# Generating Random Points on a Hypersurface with Constraints in High-Dimensional Space

Tags: probability, geometry, algorithms

Generating random points in regular geometric objects like lines, planes, cubes, and hypercubes is straightforward using uniform distributions. However, when constraints are applied, such as generating random points on a hypersurface in high-dimensional space, the task becomes more complex.

For example, consider a three-dimensional Cartesian coordinate system. I am interested in generating random points $(x, y, z)$ on the surface defined by the equation $x + y + z = 1$, while ensuring that $0 \leq x, y, z \leq 1$.

My main question is: How can I generate random points on a hypersurface in high-dimensional space while satisfying constraints defined by equations such as $f(x, y, z, \ldots) = 0$?

I am specifically seeking a method or algorithm that ensures the generated points are distributed uniformly over the hypersurface, taking into account any constraints imposed by the equation $f(x, y, z, \ldots) = 0$. Any insights or approaches would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It depends on $f$ and on the hypersurface, so I think the question is too broad in its current form.  It might be answerable given more information about $f$ and the hypersurface.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @D.W.

You are correct that the question may be too broad. I will provide further clarification.

First, let's focus on the specific example I mentioned earlier, namely generating random points on the surface defined by $x+y+z=1$ within the range $0\leq x,y,z \leq 1$ in three-dimensional space. I am interested in how to achieve this goal.

Second, if possible, regarding more general cases, let's assume that the function f represents any polynomial constraint, such as $\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i x_i^{b_i}=0$.

It is OK to only answer the first question.

Answer (score 1):

Sampling $x,y,z$ such that $x+y+z=1$ and $0\le x,y,z \le 1$ is an instance of sampling from the standard probability simplex.  For details of how to do that, see, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3227/755.

You can generalize this to sampling randomly from any convex polytope.  See, e.g., https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/60585/755.

The more general question, for any hypersurface and any $f$, depends on the hypersurface and on $f$ and on how they are represented.  Sampling might be easy or intractable, depending.

Comment: Thanks @D.W., your answer is helpful. As for the general cases, some reduction must be taken, i.e. we need to decrease the degree of freedom in high dimensional space according to the constrains.